# Client side authentication and authorization (can i and [how] should i do it)

Tags: jquery, web-services, security, authentication, active-directory

I have an external website that uses **Active Directory** for **Authentication**. The propsed design would have all **Athorization** done by the application database server. For example the user would login with username and password and the corperate people **Authenticate** against **AD**. I would then get that username and query that database for what they are allowed to see/do in my app(one small part of the whole site)

If anyone sees security flaws stop me here.

Users are allowed to access some stuff on my pages without being **authenticated**.(Don't like it but it's a buisness requirment) However when people do come to my page without being **authenticated** I would like to nicely ask them to **authenticate** with a JQuery popup. Somethinglike $.load(coperatelogon.aspx, #logondiv).dialog() after loading my page for people who are not logged on. If they click the X and donot login thats fine. They just see the page for people notloged in.

If they do **authenticate** through this dialog I want to change the content of the page to something else via client code. I want to do soemthing like make a webservice call (via JQuery ajax) based on the **authentication** they just provided. This webservice call would see what they are **authorized** to see and display some content based on that.

Is there a seciruty flaw here? Something I should do slightly differently to avoid a securty flaw?

My goal is to postback as little as possable and use as much jquery and javascript as possable; and postback as close to zero times as possable to provide the user with a smooth and enjoyable experience.

I am in the early design stage of this and am **very open** to ideas segestions recomondations or just people yelling at me and telling me it's a bad idea... etc.

Thanks!

Edit:
So it boils down to one main question:
How does a webservice call through $.ajax(...) know who the user has been authenticated as? Does the client pass this information? Can it be meddled with by a hacker?
And is using $.load(...) to show the security login box secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the short answer is yes, the webservice can securely tell who is making the call.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether or not there is an inherent security flaw in attempting to do everything Client Side, the answer is a resounding Yes.  If your authenticated (protected) content is passed to the client and then client-side code is responsible for deciding whether or not to display it you have no way to prevent unauthorized parties from figuring out how to display the content you are attempting to hide.

The *only* way to make sure unauthorized parties do not see things you do not want them to see is to keep all of the secure data server-side until they are authenticated.  Otherwise, it's only a matter of time and persistence before I find the 'key' to your obfuscated function and trick it into displaying what you would rather I not see.

Comment: Ok so i'm looking for two things. The first is what your talking about. However what if I get all the data through a webservice call? say use $.load( toget data? The second thing is can I safly get the authenticated user name to the webservice? I'll edit my question to be clear